# Not able to get values from the api to chart.js, react js

Tags: reactjs

so this is my api, which is stored in a url
"https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"

this is my api index file

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed";

export const fetchData = async () => {

  try {
    const {
      data: countryRegion ,
    } = await axios.get(url);

    return {  countryRegion };
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

in this sandbox code, i have tried to take the value of countryRegion from the api, but it appears as undefied in the console.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-nqo9n

Comment: i have upvoted your question to remove negative... when you ask qn on SO, it will be good to add relavent code snippets in your question (not just a sandbox link)

Comment: sure, thank you @gdh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are destructuring incorrectly.

```js
const { data: { countryRegion } } = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
```

**Do this in your api**

```js
const { data: countryRegion } = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
```

**Update based on the comment:**

If only country is needed in the array, just map thru it and extract `countryRegion`

```js
export const fetchData = async country => {
  try {
    let { data: countryRegion } = await axios.get(url);
    return { countryRegion: countryRegion.map(country => country.countryRegion) };
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: but this gives me a whole array, and not just one value, for example i need balue in console to be  countryRegion: {russia, US..}

Comment: just map thru it and extract the countryRegion ... i have updated the answer..